# Prevent modifier final in interfaces

Tags: java, eclipse, final, modifier

you can set within eclipse the code style to use modifier 'final' where possible.
Unfortunately this modifier is also set in interfaces. But there it doesn't make sense.
Is it possible to prevent setting the modifier 'final' for method parameters in interfaces?
Only to set it clear.. i mean not fields. These are always final and static.
I mean method params like 'param'

```
public interface MyService {
   void aMethod(String param);
}
```

instead of

```
public interface MyService {
   void aMethod(final String param);
}
```

The 'final' does not change the logic of the code, but it is unnecessary.

Comment: What does not have sence is to create a non final field in interface.

Comment: I agree with you, but i mean not fields. I mean method parameters in interfaces.

Comment: Fields in interface are always final, doesn't matter they are declared final or not. Anyway, I can't reproduce your problem. I have set "use final where possible", run clean up but my interface isn't changed.

Comment: There are no field declarations in interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't specify behavior for an `interface` vs a `class`, but you can make it stop putting `final` on parameters.

Go to `Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Clean Up`, edit the profile and choose the `Code Style` tab. At the bottom, under `Variable Declarations`, uncheck the `Parameter` check box.

Comment: I want the final modifier on class level. There it makes sense.

Comment: I think you're out of luck. I don't know of a way to set it to distinguish between classes and interfaces.